# Excel VBA Random color stored as variable

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code which generates a random color and colors "Heading" rows in my worksheet. How can I store this as a variable, and then use it to color the row? (My goal is also to use this variable to color associated column cells with the same color). Also, I'm pretty sure there is a way to clean up this code so it doesnt waste time searching empty rows?

[image]

```
Sub ColorSuperProjectHeadings()
Dim r As Byte, g As Byte, b As Byte
Dim r2 As Byte, g2 As Byte, b2 As Byte
Dim spcolor As Integer
    Dim vR(), n As Integer
    'Cells.Clear
    n = 3000
    ReDim vR(1 To n)
    For i = 1 To n
        r = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 127)
        g = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 127)
        b = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 127)
        r2 = r + 127
        g2 = g + 127
        b2 = b + 127
        'vR(i) = RGB(r, g, b)
        vR(i) = RGB(r2, g2, b2)
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        With ActiveSheet


    For Each cell In .Range("Y5:" & .Range("Y1500").End(xlDown).Address)
        If .Cells(cell.Row, 25).value = "Super Project" Then
            cell.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vR(WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, n))
        End If
    Next
End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code is working, what is the issue? Are you trying to color first column with the color of header? Or are you looking for the ways to make this run faster?

Comment: It is not clear what you really want to do, since you are using a rand function everytime you run the code it will give you different colors. If you want to retrieve the same colors to color the cells etc you can get the color number from the header or any cell that has the color from the previous run: `a=range("A1").interior.color`

Answer (score 0):

This code will color the column to the left of the heading for every heading except for the last one.  So you can play around with it to get the last bit to work but the basic functionality is there.

```
Sub ColorSuperProjectHeadings()

    Dim r As Byte, g As Byte, b As Byte
    Dim r2 As Byte, g2 As Byte, b2 As Byte
    Dim spcolor As Integer
    Dim vR() As Long
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim currentCell As Range
    Dim lastHeader As Range
    Dim lCurrentHeaderColor As Long
    Dim lLastHeaderColor As Long

    'Cells.Clear
    n = 3000
    ReDim vR(1 To n)
    For i = 1 To n
        r = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 127)
        g = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 127)
        b = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 127)
        r2 = r + 127
        g2 = g + 127
        b2 = b + 127
        'vR(i) = RGB(r, g, b)
        vR(i) = RGB(r2, g2, b2)
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        With ActiveSheet
            For Each cell In .Range("Y5:" & .Range("Y1500").End(xlDown).Address)

                Set currentCell = .Cells(cell.Row, 25)

                If currentCell.Value = "Super Project" Then
                    lCurrentHeaderColor = vR(WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, n))
                    cell.EntireRow.Interior.Color = lCurrentHeaderColor

                    If Not lastHeader Is Nothing Then
                        For i = (lastHeader.Row + 1) To (currentCell.Row - 1)
                            'Stop
                            .Cells(i, lastHeader.Column - 1).Interior.Color = lLastHeaderColor
                        Next i
                    End If

                    Set lastHeader = currentCell
                    lLastHeaderColor = lCurrentHeaderColor
                End If
            Next
        End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the questions and comments. I am really new to VBA, but not to programming, so I try to reverse engineer. This worksheet has projects (header row) and sub-projects listed below it. The code does work, but it only colors my header row with a random color.

Comment: My eventual goal is this: I want to fill the header row (A to Y) color down column A  until the next header, as shown in the screenshot. I also want to make it only color "new" headers (and "A" cells) that don't already have a color. That is why I was asking about storing the color in a variable, so I could try an put some code together to do this. The eventual goal is not to have this re-color cells that have previously been colored. That way, it will assign a random color to a new project / sub-project only. Thanks again for the assistance!

Comment: I think this is the basic code you're looking for is in the code I posted.  And you can extend it further if needed.  Did you try the code yet?

Comment: Thanks for the info- I did try the code, but I couldn’t seem to get the “A” column colored. I’m very new to VBA, but I’ll see if I can figure out the code when I get a chance.

Comment: You can change the line after the commented out Stop to this:

`.Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = lLastHeaderColor`

The `cells` function takes two arguments, the row number and the column number.  So changing `lastHeader.Column - 1` to `1` indicates column 1 because column 1 is A, column 2 is B, etc.